# Prevent label text from overlapping input text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created an input field, but when a user clicks off the user input, the span text overlays the input text. How can I prevent this from happening? I feel like I have tried everything!

```css
.label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.form-input {
  margin: 10px;
}

.label span {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: text;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #999;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 54px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  transition: all ease-out 0.1s;
}

.label:focus-within>span {
  /* Move span text up on focus */
  line-height: 26px;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
  color: rgb(29, 161, 242);
}

.label input {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 258px;
  height: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-left: 9px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

.label input:focus {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form class='form-input'>
    <label class='label'>
      <span class='span-text'>Email</span>
      <input value=''></input>
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/pen?template=GROaJZM

Comment: Note that you have an invalid Markup. `input` is an empty tag and as such has no closing tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have some changes of your html & css code with less code.

**First you need changes in Elements**:

```
 <label class='label'>
  <span class='span-text'>Email</span>
  <input value=''></input>
</label>
```

Apply To :

```
 <label class="label">
  <input type="text" class="inputText" required/>
  <span class="span-text">Email</span>
</label>
```

**Second Changes In CSS**

On Focus changes :

Remove CSS:

```
 .label input:focus {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.1s;
}
```

ADD CSS :

```
input:focus ~ .span-text,
    input:not(:focus):valid ~ .span-text{
      top: 16px;
      font-size: 12px;
      opacity: 1;
      color: rgb(29, 161, 242);
    }
```

For label tag :

Remove CSS:

```
.label span {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: text;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #999;
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 54px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  transition: all ease-out 0.1s;
}
```

Add CSS :

```
.span-text {
      position: absolute;
      pointer-events: none;
      left: 20px;
      top: 27px;
      color: #999;
      transition: 0.2s ease all;
    }
```

```css
 input:focus ~ .span-text,
    input:not(:focus):valid ~ .span-text{
      top: 16px;
      font-size: 12px;
      opacity: 1;
      color: rgb(29, 161, 242);
    }

    .inputText {
         width: 258px;
        height: 22px;
           padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 9px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .span-text {
      position: absolute;
      pointer-events: none;
      left: 20px;
      top: 27px;
      color: #999;
      transition: 0.2s ease all;
    }
```

```html
 <form class='form-input'>
    <div class="label">
      <input type="text" class="inputText" required/>
      <span class="span-text">Email</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.

Comment: Dear @tacoshy, as per asking question I have provided only solution. I have not given any solution other than this topic. you can check also

Comment: ok thanks, can i edit again with describe,
 is that fine ?

Comment: you have been aready told twice what to simply add an explaination of your "solution". What is still unclear?

Comment: i have updated code with detail, plz check

Comment: I didn't use this exact solution, but it helped me edit my original code and solve the issue. I had issues with multi-selector logic, so this really helped me fill some holes in my original code. Thank you Gaurav.



Specifically: 
 input:focus ~ .span-text,
    input:not(:focus):valid ~ .span-text{

Comment: my pleasure, Sven Dysthe